# System.IO.InvalidDataException: "End of Central Directory record could not be found. В коде

Tags: c#

вот мой код

```
private async void guna2Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string folderUrl = guna2TextBox1.Text;
    string downloadPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @".minecraft\resourcepacks\downloaded.zip");

    // Скачиваем ZIP-архив содержащий папку
    await DownloadFileFromGoogleDrive(folderUrl, downloadPath);

    // Распаковываем архив
    string extractPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @".minecraft\resourcepacks\");
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(downloadPath, extractPath);

    // Удаляем предыдущий архив
    File.Delete(downloadPath);
}

private static async Task DownloadFileFromGoogleDrive(string fileUrl, string outputPath)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(fileUrl);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно чтобы он скачивал зип архив и распаковывал  его в ту же папку

Comment: Наконец вы поняли, что надо задавать имя... Теперь с этой ошибкой, изучайте данный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960434/6808809). И еще раз повторю - `HttpClient` создается **только один раз**, а не по каждому вызову метода.

Comment: Да нет, вместо downloaded.zip у меня было ziphelper.zip, только я использовал стороннюю библиотеку для компактного кода, увы она была устаревшая, сделал по другому

Comment: Если речь про предыдущий вопрос, то я там вижу банальное указание папки, без указания полного пути (включая имени файла), и указание именно файла вам, на сколько я понял, помогло. В любом случае, это уже прошедшие события, в этом вопросе у вас либо битый архив, либо это вовсе не архив, проверяйте самостоятельно что не так, удаленно дать вам ответ - невозможно.